# How do you view the database in phpmyadmin while using Amazon AWS EC2 via SSH?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin

I am in the process of setting up a new website via Amazon AWS EC2.
I typically use SSH in order to connect to the instance and then occasionally I use FileZilla in order to move files into the /var/www/html folder.

However, I noticed that editing the MYSQL database using just this Terminal interface may not be the best way.
So I wanted to run PhpMyAdmin on the EC2 instance.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your EC2 instance has a public IP and a domain that you can use to connect to.

So of course, since it's a Linux machine like any other, you can install phpMyAdmin on it, and then navigate to `xx.xx.xx.xx/phpmyadmin` or something like `ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/phpmyadmin`, where `xx` is your Elastic IP address.

Since you're already running a web server—and I'm assuming it's Apache—all you have to do is `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` and then, in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, add the following line:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Then restart your Apache server.

Really, there's nothing you can't do with the EC2 instance that any other server could.